# WebGL VBO error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webgl, vbo

I am using Firefox to render a 3D object in a canvas using WebGL. My code was working previously, whereby a textured object was being displayed within the canvas. However upon revisiting my code, without making any changes, the object will not render and the browser console displays the following error:

```
Error: WebGL: drawArrays: no VBO bound to enabled vertex attrib index 1!
```

It is complaining about a line in my drawScene() function, shown below:

```
function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(90, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, -0.5, -4.0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(xRot), [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(yRot), [0, 1, 0]);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, manVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, manVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, manVertexTextureBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexTextureAttribute, manVertexTextureBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, manTexture);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler"), 0);

    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, manVertexIndexBuffer.numItems);
}
```

The line referred to by the error is:

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, manVertexIndexBuffer.numItems);
```

I have older versions of my code which I know to have been working but upon running these now I get the same issue.

A link to the live version of my code is [here](http://petehallwebgl.net46.net/). Any help would be much appreciated on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your setup code? Where do you look up `shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute` and `shaderProgram.vertexTextureAttribute`? And where are they enabled?

That code is not shown.

My guess is that you're not looking them up correctly. It used to work by luck but something has changed. Your driver, your GPU, your machine.

Comment: The issue turned out to be a mismatch in names for the texture attribute pointer. In `drawScene()` I referred to it as `vertexTextureAttribute` however in my Shader.js file I called it `vertexTextureCoordAttribute`. Many thanks for your answer.