# WebGL: no VBO bound to enabled vertex. Do I need "vertexAttribPointer" for vertex indices?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, vertex, glsles

**Edit:** This is not a firefox bug only, I get the same errors in chrome aswell

I get the following error:

> WebGL warning: drawElements: no VBO bound to enabled vertex attrib index 1u!

I looked around the net and it looks like the indices buffer needs a "vertexAttribPointer", but I can't find any place that explains that so I'm still unsure.

And this is my vbo render function:

```
g.activeTexture(g.TEXTURE0);
g.bindTexture(g.TEXTURE_2D, obj.texture);
g.uniform1i(g.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uSampler'), 0);
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    textureCoordAttribute, 2, g.FLOAT, g.FALSE, 0, 0 );

//vertices
g.bindBuffer(g.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.vertBuffer);
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttribLocation, obj.vertSize, g.FLOAT, g.FALSE, 0, 0 );

//white color
g.bindBuffer(g.ARRAY_BUFFER, whiteColorBuffer);
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    colorAttribLocation, 4, g.FLOAT, g.FALSE, 0, 0 );

//Texture coords
g.bindBuffer(g.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.textureBuffer);
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    textureCoordAttribute, 2, g.FLOAT, g.FALSE, 0, 0 );

//indices buffer
g.bindBuffer(g.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.indexBuffer);
setMatrixUniforms();

g.drawElements(g.TRIANGLES, obj.indexNumItems, g.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
g.bindTexture(g.TEXTURE_2D, null);
g.bindBuffer(g.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
g.bindBuffer(g.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

The indices array is correct and vertex array since it worked without textures before(although it rendered only half of the vertices).

Do I have to add indices variables to the shaders?

Edit2: This is how my `getAttribLocations` currently look like:

```
positionAttribLocation = g.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertPosition");
colorAttribLocation = g.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertColor");
textureCoordAttribute = g.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");


g.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttribLocation, // attribute location
    2, //number of elements per attribute
    gl.FLOAT, // type of element
    gl.FALSE,
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,//size of induvidual vertex
    0//offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
    );
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    colorAttribLocation,
    3,
    g.FLOAT,
    g.FALSE,
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
    );
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    textureCoordAttribute,
    2, 
    g.FLOAT,
    g.FALSE,
    0,
    0
);
g.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
g.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLocation);
g.enableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordAttribute);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebGL VBO error in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490041/webgl-vbo-error-in-firefox)

Comment: Also did I mention that there is no `gl.FALSE` ? I think I did.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I looked through the code and it's not the same problem as the suggested duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Note, the [vertexAttribPointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) method specifies the data type and location of a vertex attribute, in the currently bound `ARRAY_BUFFER`.

You have to use [bindBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bindBuffer), to bind the appropriate buffer, before you specifies the memory layout of the buffer holding the vertex attributes.
 Since some of your vertex attributes are in different buffers, you have to ensure that the corresponding buffer is bound before calling [vertexAttribPointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer).

Your code should look somehow like this:

Bind `obj.vertBuffer` buffer and define generic vertex attribute data for
`positionAttribLocation` and `colorAttribLocation`, because they are both located in the same buffer.

```
g.bindBuffer( g.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.vertBuffer );
g.vertexAttribPointer( positionAttribLocation,
    2, gl.FLOAT, false, 5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0 );
g.vertexAttribPointer( colorAttribLocation,
    3, gl.FLOAT, false, 5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT );
```

Bind `obj.texture Buffer` buffer and define generic vertex attribute data for `textureCoord Attribute`, because the texture coordinates are located in separated buffer:

```
g.bindBuffer( g.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.textureBuffer );
g.vertexAttribPointer( textureCoordAttribute, 2, g.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
```

This means your code should look like this:

```
positionAttribLocation = g.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertPosition");
colorAttribLocation = g.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertColor");
textureCoordAttribute = g.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");

g.bindBuffer( g.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.vertBuffer );  // <----------------
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttribLocation, // attribute location
    2, //number of elements per attribute
    gl.FLOAT, // type of element
    gl.FALSE,
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,//size of individual vertex
    0//offset from the beginning of a single vertex to this attribute
    );
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    colorAttribLocation,
    3,
    g.FLOAT,
    g.FALSE,
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
    );

g.bindBuffer( g.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.textureBuffer ); // <----------------
g.vertexAttribPointer(
    textureCoordAttribute,
    2, 
    g.FLOAT,
    g.FALSE,
    0,
    0
    );

g.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
g.enableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribLocation);
g.enableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordAttribute);
```